# What to choose $g(x)$ as so that $f′′(x)−2f′(x)+f(x)≥e^x$?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

> Let $f:[0,1]→R$ (the set of all real numbers) be a function. Suppose
>   the function $f$ is twice differentiable, $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and satisfies
>   $f′′(x)−2f′(x)+f(x)≥e^x$, $x∈[0,1]$.Prove that $f(x)<0$ in the interval.

Then the solution stated in my book is

> Define a function $g(x)=e^{−x}f(x)$
>
> ⇒$g′(x)=e^{−x}(f′(x)−f(x))$
>
> ⇒ $g"(x)=e^{−x}[f"(x)−2f′(x)+f(x)]$
>
> Given that $f′′(x)−2f′(x)+f(x)≥ex, x∈[0,1]$
>
> ⇒$e^{−x}(f′′(x)−2f′(x)+f(x))≥1$
>
> Hence $g′′(x)>1>0$
>
> So, $g(x)$ is concave upward and $g(0)=g(1)=0$
>
> Hence, $g(x)<0∀x∈(O,1)$
>
> ⇒ $e^{−x}f(x)<0$
>
> $f(x)<0∀x∈(O,1)$

But how to know what to choose $g(x)$ as ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty standard trick /  technique to get from a function $f$ to a linear combination of $f$ and its derivatives: Multiply by some appropriate $h$ and differentiate it - the product rule will leave us with terms mixing derivatives of $f$ and $h$.

For example, if you multiply by $e^x$ forming $g(x) = e^x f(x)$ instead and differentiate twice,

$$g'(x) = e^x f'(x) + e^x f(x)$$
$$g''(x) = e^x f''(x) + 2e^x f'(x) + e^x f(x) = e^x [f''(x) + 2f'(x) + f(x)]$$

Altering the exponential to some $e^{\lambda x}$ gives different forms, which makes this rather versatile.

Comment: Awesome!........:-D